# Formating GeoJSON file with Leaflet Ajax-plugin

Tags: leaflet, geojson

First of all I apologize for my basic english. I have to say, too, that I'm really a newby in coding.
I'm trying to create an interactive map using Leaflet (you can see it [here](http://jbouffand.free.fr/spip.php?article178&var_mode=preview)). I was able to show my geojson file using Ajax-plugin. Now I want to change the style of my GeoJSON file, but I really don't know how I can do that. Can someone explain me?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Geojson data</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
            <style>
                    html { height: 100% }
                    body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
                    #map { 
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 480px; 
                    }
            </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
            <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/master/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([42.00, 12.00], 4);
var layer = L.esri.basemapLayer('ShadedRelief').addTo(map);
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("etatsroutesdelasoie.geojson");       geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by format? How do you want to show the data from the file?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the style properties of the L.GeoJSON object. The ajax plugin is extending this object and thus, the properties valid with the L.GeoJSON object are also valid with the plugin object.

<< I assume your geometries are polygons/lines and not points >>

```
// Define a style
var myStyle = {
        "color": "#ff7800",
        "weight": 5,
        "opacity": 0.65
    };

// Add the style to your layer    
var geojson = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("etatsroutesdelasoie.geojson",{
         style:myStyle});
```

See the reference on the leaflet documentation: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-style

Comment: How would your answer change for points?